# How to solve the integral of a step function

Tags: integration

Here is explained how a step function (goes from 0 to 1 at t = 0) is related to a ramp function (see this link for detail https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/System_Metrics)

[image]

I do not understand why the integral is solved for t. I am very unfamiliar with integral solving rules and I cannot find a rule that suits this very simple function. I think I intuitively understand why it is solved for time, however. I do see that it makes sense, as t increases the response level increases (creating the ramp response). And since the area under the curve, which is a straight line, does not increase exponentially, it just seems logical that the same constant t is the result of the integral.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Look up the indicator function

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I do not understand why the integral is solved for t"?

Comment: @user170231 the integral of u(t) = t*u(t). How do we achieve this?